# How to deserialize a JSON string that has multilple objects of different type

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

I have the following json string: `"{"\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],"listInfo":{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}}"`

I have the following classes:

```
class ItemClass
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

class ListInfo
{
    public int Info1 { get; set; }
    public string Info2 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I deserialize my json string into the two different objects it contains, `ItemList` and `ListInfo`? `ItemList` should be deserialized into a `List<ItemClass>`.   I've used deserialization many times using JsonConvert but with a json string that represents a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json format is incorrect. change the `"{"\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],"listInfo":{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}}"`

to

`"{\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],\"listInfo\":{\"info1\":1,\"info2\":\"bla\"}}"`

then create a class like this

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    public List<ItemClass> ItemList { get; set; }
    public ListInfo ListInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize json to your class

```cs
string json = "{\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],\"listInfo\":{\"info1\":1,\"info2\":\"bla\"}}";
var data =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseClass>(json);
```

Comment: I see. I'm doing this in a unit test. I'm thinking I would be better off doing comparisons off of strings.  Is there a way to just get the `itemList` object out of the json string? I could then serialize the object I'm trying to compare it against and do a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

First create a temporary class to read the Json,

```cs
// New temporary class
    public class TempClass
    {
        public List<ItemClass> ItemList { get; set; }
        public ListInfo ListInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemClass
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
    }

    public class ListInfo
    {
        public int Info1 { get; set; }
        public string Info2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Above temp-class will hold the de-serialized object. Then use the following way to de-serialize and read the two different objects.

```cs
List<ItemClass> ItemsList = ((TempClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempClass>(strJsom, new JsonSerializerSettings())).ItemList;
ListInfo ListInfo = ((TempClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempClass>(strJsom, new JsonSerializerSettings())).ListInfo;
```

Now, you can traverse through the `ItemsList` to read each `ItemClass` from the Json.

Hope this helps.